# react-redux : fail to import classes

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to do the "get started with redux" course on egghead.io

However, I don't want to use the sample code on jsbin like he does.

I want to use it with my own express server. Because, what's the point of a "get started" tutorial if we cannot use it at all in real-life ?

Here's the code as used on the course : 
http://jsbin.com/wuwezo/74/edit?js,console,output

It starts with this :

```
const { connect, Provider } = ReactRedux;
const { combineReducers, createStore } = Redux;
```

So I'm trying to make those 2 lines work.

On my index.jsx file, on top of those 2 lines, I import react-redux and redux, so :

```
import ReactRedux from 'react-redux';
import Redux from 'redux';
const { connect, Provider } = ReactRedux;
const { combineReducers, createStore } = Redux;
```

Then I run webpack (I use babel loader) : it places the bundle.js file in the public directory (where index.html is).
Then I run the express server, and visit index.html.

I get this in the console : 
Firefox:
"TypeError: _reactRedux2.default is undefined[Learn More]"

Chrome: 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined"

Googling the firefox error, I get nothing.

But with Chrome, I understand I get undefined using "const {...}".

Is it a babel loader issue ?

What am I missing ?

Comment: Also check out https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app - lets you concentrate on React without spending time on configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use es6 imports when those modules aren't es6 modules. Just go back to using require.

```
const { connect, Provider } = require('react-redux');
const { combineReducers, createStore } = require('redux');
```

The following options should also work for you:

```
import * as ReactRedux from 'react-redux';
import * as Redux from 'redux';
const { connect, Provider } = ReactRedux;
const { combineReducers, createStore } = Redux;
```

And:

```
import { connect, Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { combineReducers, createStore }  from 'redux';
```

Comment: But what would I do make code works using the same 2 lines ?    `const { connect, Provider } = ReactRedux;
const { combineReducers, createStore } = Redux;`

Comment: Is it not sufficient to do: `const ReactRedux = require('react-redux')` prior?

Comment: Thanks!  I can do `import React from 'react';`, and it will work in the code. But for ReactRedux and Redux, I have to use `const ReactRedux = require('react-redux');
const Redux = require('redux');`    OR  `import {connect} from 'react-redux';`

Answer (score 0):

To use es6, you can use `"presets": ["es2016"]` in your webpack.
For documentation, you can refer [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2016/)